# blue question mark for jar file in the lib folder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

When I use maven **clean and install** functions, the console shows missing those ten jar files. Then I am trying to both drag the ten jar files to the lib folder and "Properites -> Java Build Path" ->"Libraries -> Add External JARs". However when I try to clean and install the maven the problems still exists. And those "missing" jar files under **"lib"** got blue question marks
[image]
[image]

Comment: that is because it is not under version control, i.e. if you are using git - right click and then select  Team -> Add to Index , it will change, but ideally if you are using a maven project you shouldn't commit your jars

Comment: Okay I will try it

Comment: Commit those files. Go to Team-> Commit, and make sure that those file must be selected at the time of commit.As by default new files get unchecked.

Comment: @Riddhi Gohil my project is a local file and it is a solo project which doesnot involve online repository

Comment: Okk, actually that symbol shows that your project is Connected to Git.. So I thought ..

Answer (score 0):

Include those jar file entries in your pom.xml . The maven build will check for needed jar files in maven repository, it will not go to repository if you have manually dragged those jars to your lib folder.

Comment: Do u mean the "lib" folder under the "WEB-INF" or "Libraries" under "Java Resources"?

Comment: @Sheldon: The blue mark came on those jar files because it was not under version control or it was new files that yet not committed to svn repository. Usually in maven projects we will not commit jar files. 
Your actual problem here is the maven build failure, right? 
Include those missing jar files entries in your pom.xml , no need to add those jar files as external library.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple commit the file jar and the blue mark question will be solved.

Comment: my project is a solo local project doesnot involve git or and svn repository

Comment: If that just simple remove git or svn in your project, cause the symbol is indicate that you are using git or svn and the blue mark question mean that the file is not under version control.